# Keep Getting error: Missing '()' invoking a constructor

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error with Missing '()'invoking a constructor

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  NProgress.start(), (new WOW).init(), $(".game-img img, .recent-played img, .cat-games img, .lazy-avatar").unveil(100, function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
      this.style.opacity = 1
    })
  }), setTimeout(function() {
    NProgress.done()
  }, 1e3)
});
```

Comment: `(new WOW)` -> `(new WOW())` ?

Comment: Not really an error, just a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script invokes a constructor (which is a special method defined inside a class) that is automatically called (if it exists) upon class creation.

The only class being created in your script seems to be `WOW`.

It's missing a `()` and thus the fix would be:

```
NProgress.start(), (new WOW()).init() ....
```